# How to get sp user group name through scripting in sharepoint 2010 fba web application?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

how to get current logged user group name through script in sharepoint 2010 web application at configuration level.

Any one help!

Answer (score 0):

Script being what exactly? C# JavaScript/jQuery?

I interpret script as client-side so that's how I'm answering.

You can call the UserGroup webservice, `http://<Site>/_vti_bin/usergroup.asmx`,  and do a GetGroupCollectionFromUser operation to return the group collection for the current user.  This will tell you all the groups the current user belongs to and in turn do whatever you need to do.